# Is there a way to execute background task in application on Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, background, telerik

I have an app written in javascript (Cordova), it uses Telerik App Platform.
Is there a plugin that allows to execute tasks on background (f. e. download a package when app starts)? 
As far as I can see, such plugins only exist for iOS, and I want to support both Android and iOS.